# Python 'is' operator behavioral difference while running as a script and running on terminal

Tags: python-2.7

I came across different behavior of 'is' in python.

```
n = 50000
if n is 50000 :   #comparison is success
    print "Its 50k" #Holds true
```

Switch over to python 'Terminal' (command prompt)

```
>>> n = 50000
>>> n is 50000
False
```

Why is the behavior different? 
Version: 2.7.5+

Comment: `is` tests identity, not equality.  See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/132988/235698).

Comment: Because the compiler created *one* code block in a script, and compiles each expression separately in the interactive interpreter. So in the script the compiler re-uses the `50000` object, in the interpreter it doesn't.

Comment: But just in case this wasn't clear, *never use `is`* when you need to test for equality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your comment answers his question. The proposed dupe *does not* (it only explains one part of his problem). In other words, if you remove your comment and someone stumbles on this question and then reads the dupe, will he get an answer?

Comment: @Fermiparadox: without a clarification stating otherwise, this is a X-Y problem.  They almost certainly were confused why `is` doesn't work the way they expected it to, and are not really interested in the implementation details.